# how to update/sync a pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-pull, github-for-windows

In my local machine I cloned a repository using this command below,

```
git clone https://github.com/kp/ml_project.git
```

Now in the original project there was a pull request made and it's pull request number is 22. So I've added the pull request using these below commands.

```
cd ml_project
git fetch origin pull/22/head:pr22
```

Now after few days in the pull request 22 they were new commits added and I want those to be available to me. What can I do? How can I update/fetch new commits into my branch pr22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have branch `pr22` checked out,<sup>1</sup> then run the same `git fetch`.  (Then you can `git checkout` the branch again, if you want.)

If they have only *added* commits, it will run fine.  If they *replaced* commits (took some out, put in some different ones instead), e.g., after a rebase, you'll get a "non-fast-forward" error.

If you would like to throw out your old `pr22` value and store the new updated tip anyway, simply force the fetch to update despite the not-a-fast-forward condition. To force the fetch, you can use `git fetch --force`—this tells `git fetch` to set the force flag on *every* refname update—or use a plus-sign `+` character on the specific refspec containing a ref you wish to force:

```
git fetch origin +refs/pull/22/head:refs/heads/pr22
```

(In this case, there's only one refspec,<sup>2</sup> so `+` and `--force` do the same thing.  Here I have fully spelled out both refs in the single refspec.  As you've seen, you can abbreviate the refs in common cases.  Spelling them out in full is wise in scripts, though, as Git will resolve partial refs to full ones in surprising ways sometimes.)

---

<sup>1</sup>For instance, run `git checkout master` to switch away, or just use `git checkout --detach` to get into "detached HEAD" mode on the current commit.  Either of these avoid the pitfalls that "update my current branch name" present.

<sup>2</sup>A *refspec* is, roughly, a pair of *refs* or *references* with a colon between them: `pull/22/head:pr22` is an example of a refspec.  Prefixing a refspec with the plus sign makes it a *forced* update.  For more about these, see [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch.html) and [the `git push` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

A *ref* is any branch name like `master`, tag name like `v2.1`, remote-tracking name like `origin/master`, or any other such name.  *All* of these names, in Git, are *refs*.  A *branch name* is simply a ref whose full name starts with `refs/heads/` and a *tag name* is simply a ref whose full name starts with `refs/tags/`.  Git normally abbreviates these refs by stripping off the `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/` part for convenience.

When you use the abbreviated form, Git has to guess what the full name should be.  If you have a branch named `master` *and* a *tag* named `master` too, Git will guess "tag" first—so don't do that, and in scripts, spell out the full name.

Comment: Thank you ... Can you tell me what is refs? What does it mean?

Comment: i tried but it returns fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/pr22 of non-bare repository

Comment: Oh, you have it *checked out* right now. Check out some other branch first, then do it again.